# DAG（ワークフロー）のトリガーにするためのクライアント ID が取得できません

Tags: python

GCP CloudComposerについての質問です。

DAG（ワークフロー）のトリガーにする関数の検証をするため、
以下の記事のpythonコードを参考に、クライアント ID を取得したいのですが

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/rest/get_client_id.py

プログラムを実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。

出ているエラーは以下になります。

```
# 実行コマンド
python3 id.py 'project_id' 'location' 'composer_environment'
# エラー
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id.py", line 69, in <module>
    args.project_id, args.location, args.composer_environment)
  File "id.py", line 42, in get_client_id
    airflow_uri = environment_data['config']['airflow_uri']
KeyError: 'config
```

出ているエラーの意味は　
airflow uriでのエラーが起きています。
どうしたらエラーがおさまるでしょうか？

Comment: `python3 get_client_id.py -h` を実行してみると `project_id`, `location`, `composer_environment` は **positional arguments** と表示されます。なので、例えば仮に `project_id` が `1`, `location` が `Tokyo`, `composer_environment` が `env` の場合には `python3 id.py '1' 'Tokyo' 'env'` とします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
指定のように引数入れて実行したのですが、
airflow uriでのエラーが起きています。
どうしたらエラーがおさまるでしょうか？
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id.py", line 69, in <module>
    args.project_id, args.location, args.composer_environment)
  File "id.py", line 42, in get_client_id
    airflow_uri = environment_data['config']['airflow_uri']
KeyError: 'config

Comment: そうですね、、現時点で言えるのは「実際に利用している `project_id`, `location`, `composer_environment` を指定する事」です。